# Meaning of "twitching mass of humanity"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> It was Quasimodo Sunday, one week after
>   Easter. The child who had been left that day
>   was being inspected by two old women.
>   “How strange! What can it be?”
>   “It can’t really be a child, Agnes. Maybe it’s
>   a deformed ape.”
>   “It’s so ugly! Perhaps we should throw it
>   into the river or the fire.”
>   “Surely no one will claim this one! I don’t
>   think it’s really a baby. My guess is that this
>   ittle monster is about four years old.”
>   Indeed, it was not a newborn baby. It was
>   a **twitching mass of humanity** in a canvas bag.
>   The head peeping out was very disfigured!
>   There was a forest of red hair, one eye, a
>   mouth, and a few teeth. The eye was weeping,
>   the mouth was crying, and the teeth seemed
>   to want only to bite.

Dose it mean that he was a creature that was made suddenly and carelessly in a short time?

Can we say here "mass" is: creature?

This context is from: The Hunchback of Notre dame adapted by Emily Hutchinson.

Comment: Ref. OP's [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192444/meaning-of-screaming-bundle).

Comment: but it was another question!

Comment: Yes, just showing some history.

Comment: The rest of the quotation illustrates what is meant - and remember that a comment on the previous question points out that it is a translation from French.

Comment: OP, you really need to get used to figurative language in literature. Otherwise you are going to have a question for every other sentence you read.

Comment: @Robusto as shown by the two questions on the same passage...

Comment: Yes, you are right. and I guess something maybe as your answer but as I am translating, your answer give me more idea to translate better. Lots of thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this quote, the word mass would most nearly mean "large amount of." This is seen in definition 1a of the second noun on [Marriam-Webster.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mass)

The entire phrase means that there was a human in the bag, and it was large and twitching.